# Should the postdoc interview focus on my research findings or transferrable skills that could be value of the research team that I am applying?

Tags: phd, postdocs, job-search, interview

I will have a postdoc interview soon. I previously ask our community about whether I should prepare a PowerPoint. I got some great advice about preparing a deck of slides that would help me to clarify my thinking about what to say.

I would like to ask your opinion about the content. Should I talk about my research findings at all and instead focus on what research skills I could bring to the lab? Of course, scholars are excited about hearing cool research findings but I have a sense that, pragmatically speaking, they would want to hear more about my skills. Given time restrictions, what would be the best strategy to optimize my interview time to promote myself?

I appreciate your advice and insights.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it doesn't need to be either-or. Make it both. But don't do it in two parts. Weave it together if at all possible.

But another reason this is happening is that they want to know something about you as a person and as a potential colleague. How do you present yourself. Are you formal? Pedantic? Friendly? Lots of things. Along with that, they want some idea about how you go about handling such public talks. How do you present ideas whatever they are. If you seem natural it will probably help. Unfortunately that normally comes with a lot of practice over time. But they probably understand that.